# Why does VZWPIX.com (Email to MMS) defer 451 4.1.0? (EXIM Log)

Tags: email, smtp, deferred, exim

I have a small texting service that is not blacklisted by cloudmark barracuda nor 100+ other respected anti-spam entities yet after roughly 1000 deliveries to vzwpix.com domain possible grey list happening? Also have exim.pl and exim.conf randomize 3 IP's for outgoing delivery only. SPF and DKIM correct through all IPs for reputation status. I searched for 2 weeks little to find last resort contact cloudfilter aka cloudmark. Thanx for your inputs not a huge deal at the moment.

PS: IP Reputation status clear since May 17'

---

```
Connecting to smtpin01-mms.vzw.a.cloudfilter.net [52.205.80.105]:25 from my.mailserver.ip.address ... connected
SMTP<< 220 vzw-ibgw-5003a.stratus.cloudmark.com cmsmtp ESMTP server ready
SMTP>> EHLO mail.mydomain.com
SMTP<< 250-vzw-ibgw-5003a.stratus.cloudmark.com hello [my.mailserver.ip.address], pleased to meet you
     250-HELP
     250-SIZE 30000000
     250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
     250-8BITMIME
     250-STARTTLS
     250 OK
SMTP>> STARTTLS
SMTP<< 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
SMTP>> EHLO mail.mydomain.com
SMTP<< 250-vzw-ibgw-5003a.stratus.cloudmark.com hello [my.mailserver.ip.address], pleased to meet you
     250-HELP
     250-SIZE 30000000
     250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
     250-8BITMIME
     250 OK
SMTP>> MAIL FROM:<customer@mydomain.com> SIZE=1946
SMTP<< 452 4.1.0 <customer@mydomain.com> requested action aborted: try  again later
LOG: MAIN
SMTP error from remote mail server after MAIL FROM:<customer@mydomain.com> SIZE=1946: 452 4.1.0 <customer@mydomain.com> requested action aborted: try again later
SMTP>> QUIT
SMTP(close)>>
```